# Redes Neurais - Weka - O que é o parâmetro Threshold?

Tags: java, weka

Ao criar um modelo preditivo de dados utilizando rede neural no weka o que significa o Threshold e como esse parâmetro influencia nos cálculos do valor previsto?

Answer (score 0):

Usado para encerrar o teste de validação. O valor determina quantas vezes seguidas o erro do conjunto de validação pode piorar antes que o treinamento seja encerrado.